# Literature on recusively applying predicated transformations to a symbol tree to match some target symbol tree

Tags: symbolic-execution

I am working on a problem that can be simplified to consist of the following:

- an initial symbol tree
- a list of interpretations (an interpretation is a transformation guarded by a predicate)
- a predicate describing what the target symbol tree should look like

Where the goal is to find a path from the initial symbol tree to some symbol tree that matches the predicate of the target symbol tree via the given list of interpretations.

To complicate matters, a transformation can be from a symbol tree to symbol tree, but it might also transform a symbol tree to a new interpretation, which will then be added to the list of available interpretations. Also, predicates and transformations can have access to extra information such as the context and in turn can also request to try and interpret a symbol a certain way (i.e. the interpretation process is recursive).

If implemented naively, this can get computationally expensive really fast, so several optimizations are added to make it more feasible to compute, e.g. requiring transformations to be transparant about on what kind of symbols they will work, so transformations can be ruled out as soon as possible.

The problem described above, seems to me common enough, so I assume there is some existing body of literature that has researched this problem. I tried searching for it, but I have only found literature about very specialized versions of this problem that e.g. only allow certain builtin predicates and where the transformation was not a function, but was a direct mapping to some other symbol tree.

It might be that I just have not yet found the right terminology or that my current approach is considered to be to general, such that people already ruled it out as infeasible, and thus has not received any real attention in literature.

Does anyone know of any literature about the problem I described above? It would be helpful to see what other people have done in this problem domain, to e.g see other approaches, problems and solutions I might have overlooked so far.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  The inputs are the initial tree, the target tree, and the list of transformations?  What's the output?  It seems the output is a list of transformations, but what degrees of freedom are there?  Are we allowed to reorder the transformations?  Are we allowed to duplicate them?  Also, what is the space of transformations?  For instance, is every transformation a [tree transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_transducer).  Without any restrictions on the space of transformations, this is surely hard, so you'll need to narrow this somehow.

Comment: The output is a symbol tree matching the output predicate. It might take many intermediate symbol trees to get there. The list of interpretations is allowed to be reordered and filtered. I am not sure what the point is of duplicating interpretations? The transformations go from symbol tree to symbol tree, or symbol tree to interpretation, but besides the symbol tree there are more inputs that could be used to produce the result. You are allowed to add extra restrictions if necessary, e.g. I already require to know beforehand if a transformation results in a interpretation.

Comment: OK.  This smells like it might be NP-hard (e.g., via a reduction from Hamiltonian path or the route inspection problem or something like that).